# How to Change my default shell on server?

Tags: linux, shell, remote-server

I was assigned an account for log in to a remote server, and I want to change my default shell.

I tried `chsh` command but it says: `chsh: "/public/home/{my_id}/bin/zsh" is not listed in /etc/shells.`

Answer (score 3):

If you don't have permission to install zsh system wide, a quick fix is to append `exec ~/bin/zsh -l` to `~/.bash_profile` (if bash is the current shell), or an equivalent rc file for the current login shell.

- `zsh -l` starts zsh as a login shell.
- `exec COMMAND` replaces the current process with COMMAND, so you'll only have to type exit (or press ctrl+d) once.
- `~/.bash_profile` is executed when bash starts as a login shell, you can still run command `bash` normally.

Depending what is in `~/.bash_profile` (or equivalent), you may wish to avoid executing its other contents, by putting `exec ~/bin/zsh -l` at the start of the file (not the end), and copy/port anything important over to the zsh equivalent, `$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile`.

I might also do `export SHELL="$HOME/bin/zsh"`, although I'm unsure of the full effects of setting SHELL differently to that specified for your user in `/etc/passwd`, to a shell not in `/etc/shells`, and to a shell binary in your home path.

Comment: Thanks, it works! And thanks for reminds me that `exec` can replace current process with new image.

Answer (score 0):

1. First check all the shells available on your linux system

```
cat /etc/shells
```

2. Use chsh command line utility for changing a login shell with the -s or –shell option like this.

```
# chsh --shell /bin/sh tecmint
```

Comment: My server doesn't have `zsh` so I installed it myself, it's located in `~/bin/zsh`, and I don't have the permission to edit `/etc/shells/`

Comment: You can still run it by doing ~/bin/zsh

Comment: @stark it works but when I want to quit I have to enter `exit` twice :(